# Bounded subset of the integers has a maximum (using monotone sequence version of completeness)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm reading *A companion to Analysis* by Körner, and so far he has only introduced completeness saying that a monotone sequence which is bounded above converges. I want to prove that every non-empty bounded subset of the integers has a maximum. Let's call integers bounded subset $A$.

That there is a maximum means that there exist $a_0 \in A$ such that $a_0 \geq a$ whenever $a \in A$

I argue by contradiction. Negating that there is a maximum we have:

$\forall a_0 \in A$ there exist a $a \in A$ such that $a \gt a_0$

Reformulating we have:

$\forall a_n \in A$ there exists a $a_{n + 1} \in A$ such that $a_{n + 1} \gt a_n$

So this way we can construct a increasing monotone sequence $\{a_n\}$ bounded above, and by completeness it converges $a_n \rightarrow a$.

Because $a_{n + 1} \gt a_n$ and every $a_n$ is an integer we have that $a_{n + 1} \geq a_n + 1$.

Given $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, because $a_n \rightarrow a$, we have there exist a $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $|a_n - a| \lt \varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. This means that $-\frac{1}{2} < a_n - a < \frac{1}{2}$, and $a < a_n + \frac{1}{2} = a_n + 1 - \frac{1}{2} \leq a_{n + 1} - \frac{1}{2}$, so $|a_{n + 1} - a| > \frac{1}{2}$ which is a contradiction (because $n + 1 \gt n \geq N$).

Is this correct? I know it's not necessary to use axiom of completeness for this proof, but I want to follow the book. Is there a simpler proof?

Answer (score 2):

You might like this proof that does not use completeness:

Suppose $A$ is a nonempty subset of the integers that has no maximum.
Consider the statement $P(s)$: there exists $a \in A$ with $a > s$.

If $a_0$ is a member of $A$, then $P(a_0 - 1)$ is true.
For any integer $s$, suppose $P(s)$ is true, i.e. there exists $a \in A$ with $a > s$.  Since $a$ is not the maximum of $A$, there exists $b \in A$ with $b > a$.
Thus $b > s+1$, so $P(s+1)$ is true.

By mathematical induction, $P(s)$ is true for all integers $s \ge a_0 - 1$.  But then $A$ is not bounded above.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

First, you have to define what an integer is.  The integers are defined as:

- $~1~$ is the set of positive integers.
  In fact, $~1~$ is the smallest positive integer.
- If $~n~$ is in the set of positive integers, then so is $~n+1.~$
- Then, $~0~$ is defined as $~1 - 1,~$ and the set of negative integers are defined as the additive inverses to the set of positive integers.

Therefore, you have that if $~n~$ is any integer, so is $~n+1,~$ and so is $~n-1.$  Further, you have that if $~n~$ is any integer, the smallest integer greater than $~n~$ is $~n+1,~$ and the largest integer less than $~n~$ is $~n-1.$

Suppose that you have some subset of the integers $~M~$ that is bounded above.  Since $~M \subset \Bbb{R},~$ it has a least upper bound $~b \in \Bbb{R}.$

One of the consequences of the fact that $~\Bbb{Z}~$ is unbounded **above**, is that there must exist an integer $~n~$ such that $~n > b.~$

Now, consider the following algorithm.  If $~n > b~$ and $~(n-1) \leq b,~$ then designate $~(n-1)~$ as the $~\lfloor b\rfloor~$ (i.e. the *floor* of $~b~$).  If (instead), $~n-1 > b,~$ then check $~n-2,~$ and so forth.  Since it is assumed that both $~n~$ and $~b~$ are finite numbers, this algorithm must finish in a finite number of steps.

Therefore, $~\lfloor b\rfloor~$ must exist.  Since, by definition, there is no integer $~n~$ such that $~\lfloor b\rfloor < n < b,~$ you must have that $~\lfloor b\rfloor~$ is also an upper bound to $~M.~$

Furthermore, since $~b~$ is defined to be the least upper bound to $~M,~$ and since $~\lfloor b\rfloor~$ is also an upper bound to $~M,~$ and since (by definition), $~\lfloor b\rfloor \leq b,~$ you must have that $~\lfloor b\rfloor = b.~$

Therefore, the least upper bound $~b~$ to $~M~$ must be an integer.  Suppose that $~b \not\in M.~$  Since $~b~$ is an integer, the next smallest integer $~b - 1,~$ must also be an upper bound to $~M.~$

This contradicts the assumption that $~b~$ is the least upper bound of $~M.~$  Therefore, $~b~$ must be an element in $~M.~$  Since, by definition, $~b~$ must be greater than any other element in $~M,~$ the set $~M~$ must contain its own maximum element.